# How to add abiotic variables (temperature, water etc) as lines to bar graphs in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I want to add the temperature and water annual data as lines behind the bar graphs for each facet_grid.

```
sp.abd <- sample(1:48, replace = TRUE)
sp <- rep(c("A","B","temp","water"), each = 96)
plot <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1,2), time = 48)))
month <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1:12), time = 8)))

df <- data.frame(month, sp, sp.abd, plot)

ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y=sp.abd, fill = sp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(plot~sp) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

I want something that looks like this..

[image]

I tried it with the secondary axis also, but I had very little luck. Here is the code and graph

```
sp.abd <- sample(1:48, replace = TRUE)
sp <- rep(c("A","B"), each = 24)
plot <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1,2), time = 24)))
month <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1:12), time = 4)))
temp <- rnorm(48, 15, 5)
water <- rnorm(48, 15, 5)

df <- data.frame(month, sp, sp.abd, temp, water, plot)

coeff <- 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = month)) + 
  facet_grid(plot~sp) + theme_classic() +
  geom_bar( aes(y=sp.abd), stat = "identity", size=2) +
  geom_line( aes(y=temp), size=2, color="Red") + 
  geom_line( aes(y=water), size=2, color="Blue") +

  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Temperature (Celsius °)/ Moisture",
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name="sp.abd")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suit?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
sp.abd <- sample(1:48, replace = TRUE)
sp <- rep(c("A","B"), each = 24)
plot <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1,2), time = 24)))
month <- as.factor(as.numeric(rep(c(1:12), time = 4)))
temp <- rnorm(48, 15, 5)
water <- rnorm(48, 15, 5)

df <- data.frame(month, sp, sp.abd, temp, water, plot)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(month, sp, sp.abd, plot)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = month, y=sp.abd, fill = sp),
           stat = "identity") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = month, y = value + 125,
                  group = name, color = name),
              formula = "y ~ x", method = "loess",
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = month, y = value + 125,
                  group = name, color = name),
              formula = "y ~ x", method = "loess",
              se = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(plot~sp) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: example_1.png]